# Show $ \hat{F}_n(b) := \frac{1}{n} \cdot$ |{ $i \in$ {$1,...,n$} : $x_i \leq b$}| is a distribution function on $\mathbb{R}^q$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

$ \hat{F}_n(b) := \frac{1}{n} \cdot$ |{ $i \in$ {$1,...,n$} : $x_i \leq b$}| $ =\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{1}_{x_i}((-\infty,b]). $ .

We want that:

$\hat{F}_n(b)$ is non-decreasing. (Check)

$\hat{F}_n(b)$ $\rightarrow 0$ for $b \rightarrow -\infty$.

$\hat{F}_n(b)$ $\rightarrow 1$ for $b \rightarrow \infty$.

$\hat{F}_n$ is right-continuous, which means $\hat{F}_n(b_{-}) = \lim_{c \nearrow b}\hat{F}_n(c) $.

I hope that I didn't forget one criterion. 
Here is my idea for the properties:
Since  $\mathbb{1}_{x_i}((-\infty,-\infty)) = 0$ and $\mathbb{1}_{x_i}((-\infty,\infty)) = 1$ we have  that $\hat{F}_n(b)$ $\rightarrow 0$ for $b \rightarrow -\infty$ and $\hat{F}_n(b)$ $\rightarrow 1$ for $b \rightarrow \infty$. Is this enough? How can I show  that  $\hat{F}_n$ right-continuous?

Comment: Who are the $x_i$?

Comment: Realizations of random variables $ x_1, x_2, ... : ( A, B, \mathbb{P}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^p, \mathbb{B}^p) $, with $(A,B,\mathbb{P})$ probability space.